# Unable to install Rasa 1.7.0 on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, rasa

I have been trying to install rasa on my Window 10 machine. But no success so far. Environment wise I have python 3.7, pip 20.3. When I give **pip install rasa==1.7.0** on anaconda powershell it takes ages to download the dependencies and finally errors out as:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 224, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 321, in run
    reqs, check_supported_wheels=not options.target_dir
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 122, in resolve
    requirements, max_rounds=try_to_avoid_resolution_too_deep,
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 445, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 325, in resolve
    for item in self.state.criteria.items()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 326, in <listcomp>
    if not self._is_current_pin_satisfying(*item)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 193, in _is_current_pin_satisfying
    for r in criterion.iter_requirement()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iter_requirement'
```

I could not find much details on this. As already dependencies were taking lot of time, I came across [New resolver takes time](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9187) article which states pip 20.3 takes more time. One way to solve it is to give exact versions of dependencies which I was not sure of as am quite new to rasa. I tried using older resolver as **pip install rasa==1.7.0 --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver**. After sometime it errored out as below:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jaxlib>=0.1.51 (from dopamine-rl->tensor2tensor~=1.14.0->rasa==1.7.0) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jaxlib>=0.1.51 (from dopamine-rl->tensor2tensor~=1.14.0->rasa==1.7.0)
```

To resolve this: I did dopamine install of different version as suggested [here](https://forum.rasa.com/t/cannot-jaxlib-error-in-rasa-x-0-23-5-installing/32627) as I was not sure what version to go with. The packages started downloading and finally gave the dependency conflict error, occurred due to usage of legacy resolver.

```
ERROR: pip's legacy dependency resolver does not consider dependency conflicts when selecting packages. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tensorflow-metadata 0.26.0 requires absl-py<0.11,>=0.9, but you'll have absl-py 0.11.0 which is incompatible.
kfac 0.2.3 requires tensorflow-probability==0.8, but you'll have tensorflow-probability 0.7.0 which is incompatible.
```

If we go with new resolver then it takes lot of time in resolving dependencies. Also we are not sure what all dependency versions needs to be downloaded to fine tune it.

Any help pointers here would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I tied the following command sequence:

```
pip install dopamine-rl==3.0.1
pip install absl-py>=0.9
pip install rasa==1.7.0 --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver
```

Rasa got installed. Installed tensor-flow after this as **conda install tensorflow==1.15.0**. Now when tried to check tensorflow version, got the below warning and error.

```
The TensorFlow Distributions library has moved to TensorFlow Probability (https://github.com/tensorflow/probability). You should update all references to use `tfp.distributions` instead of `tf.distributions`.
    
ImportError: cannot import name 'Layer' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer' (C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you already started a discussion on Rasa Forum, let's move the conversation there! :) https://forum.rasa.com/t/unable-to-install-rasa-1-7-0/38313

Comment: Sure, I am good with either forums :). Hoping to get some insights from experienced guys.